Could not resolve @prisma/client despite the installation that we just tried
I have a turbo repo setup and this is a problem which comes on its own and go on its own, till now i was only experiencing this in local setup but now i am also experiencing it in prod.
getting this error:
Error: Could not resolve @prisma/client despite the installation that we just tried.
Please try to install it by hand with npm i @prisma/client and rerun npx "prisma generate" .

tried all the ways listed on github issues and discussions but none work, they did worked in the past but not now.
I am using

node v18
prisma and prismaClient v5.22
with neon as an adapter

The problem i have noticed is this mostly occurs in monorepo setup and same case here the .prisam and @prisma/client files which should lie in root node_modules is instead in the packages/db
